# how to format input value same time of key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Arrange my input (phone number) value according to below format

```
<input type="text" value="123-456-7890">
```

if type 1234567890 it will set like 123-456-7890

Comment: http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/phone/

Comment: You could use a change listener and append the hyphen, when a certain amount of digits have been entered.

Comment: You want to get the value in that format or you want that the number inside the field should get replaced in that format?

Comment: thank for your response Jaybird but i don't want to use plugin

Comment: hello  Mayank,

i want that number inside the field and replaced in that format?

Comment: @zero - If you got it working fine please select the right answer. It would be helpful for others too

Answer (score 2):

```
var $phone=1234567890
$phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
```

Output:

```
123-456-7890
```

**Edit:**
*Updated JsFiddle with keyup* 
Output in a div - Phone number hardcoded
http://jsfiddle.net/smileyface/mu95g83n/  
Output in a div
http://jsfiddle.net/smileyface/mu95g83n/17/
Output inside textbox itself
http://jsfiddle.net/smileyface/mu95g83n/20/

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //Run when document is ready (page loaded)
  $('#txtval').keyup(function count() { //on every key up inside textbox
    var $input = this.value;

    if ($input.length == 3) {
      $('#txtval').val($input + "-"); //add hiphen to input after 3 letters
    }
    if ($input.length == 7) {
      $input = $input.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1-$2")
      $('#txtval').val($input + "-"); //add hiphen after 7 letters
    }
    if ($input.length == 11) {
      $input = $input.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
      $('#txtval').val($input); //show phone number as expected
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter Phone# : <input type="text" id="txtval" maxlength="12" />
```

Comment: Let me know if you want any change in this

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
  var length = 0;
  length = $('#txtval').val().length;
  if (length == 3 || length == 7) {
    $('#txtval').val($('#txtval').val().concat('-'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Phone: <input type="text" id="txtval" value="" placeholder="Enter your Phone" />
```

Comment: Code should always come with an explanation. Please explain the code above.